# POST of form data failing with 405 Error: NGINX reverse proxy using Javascript (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nginx, reverse-proxy, restful-url

Using the following HTML form, I am able to update a database record:

```
<form id="update_form" action="/contact_info" method="post">
          <label for="name">
                  <h3 class="update_form">First and Last Name:</h3></label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="50" value="David Smith"><label for="address">
                  <h3 class="update_form">Address:</h3></label><input type="text" id="address" name="address" size="50" value="La La Land Las Vegas, NV 21223"><label for="address">
                  <h3 class="update_form">Email Address:</h3></label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="50" value="bugs@roadrunner.com"><br>
          <input class="button" type="submit" value="Update"> 
          <input class="button" type="submit" value="Done"></form>
```

I want to do the same thing using Javascript.  I borrowed the following code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript); meanwhile, it’s not working: a 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) exception is being thrown.  To be precise, it is failing at XHR.send( FD ) (see below for context).

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function () {
  function sendData() {
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Bind the FormData object and the form element
    const FD = new FormData( form );

    // Define what happens on successful data submission
    XHR.addEventListener( "load", function(event) {
      alert( event.target.responseText );
    });

    // Define what happens in case of error
    XHR.addEventListener( "error", function( event ) {
      alert( 'Oops! Something went wrong.' );
    });

    // Set up our request
    XHR.open( "POST", "http://localhost:8081/contact_info" );

   // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
   XHR.send( FD );
}

// Access the form element...
const form = document.getElementById( "update_form" );

// ...and take over its submit event.
form.addEventListener( "submit", function ( event ) {
event.preventDefault();

sendData();
});
});
```

Again, the vanilla HTML form via POST works flawlessly; introducing Javascript into the equation to do something functionally equivalent is not working.  I’m using NGINX to field update/POST requests via the HTML form and which it hands off to a RESTful service that talks to a Postgres database instance.

To my knowledge, under NGINX serving certain static content leads to this issue, but this doesn’t apply to my situation.  Any hints about how I might approach debugging this problem would be greatly appreciated.  FYI, my NGINX configuration file looks like this:

```
worker_processes auto;
events {
worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
     listen 8080;
     server_name _;
     index index.html;
     location / {
       root /opt/app;
       try_files $uri /index.html;
     }
     location /contact_info{
       proxy_method POST;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/contact_info;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Check what is the request sent in the network tab of your browser

Comment: POST http://localhost/contact_info 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)

Comment: This could indicate a redirect happening somewhere and converting the POST request to a GET request

Comment: In wireshark this is what I'm seeing (consecutive summaries from the log [263-265]):      
263 14.037589522 ::1 ::1 HTTP 1073 POST /contact_info HTTP/1.1 

264 14.037611133 ::1 ::1 TCP 86 80 → 59170 [ACK] Seq=3156 Ack=2307 Win=64640 Len=0 TSval=3970245564 TSecr=3970245564

265 14.038355111 ::1 ::1 HTTP 269 HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED  (text/plain)

Comment: Sometime server are configured to have a trailing slash at the end, if you don't pass, they will do a redirect to a url with `/` appended. That also may be a case with you, just have a look

Comment: I think I found the problem:

Status 405
METHOD NOT ALLOWED
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 183 B (18 B size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin